# Can I use VeraCrypt to encrypt both drives in my laptop?

Tags: windows-10, truecrypt, veracrypt

I have Windows 10 installed on a 64 GB SSD (C:) and user files (and most programs) on a 512 GB hard drive (D:). Is it possible to encrypt both drives with VeraCrypt (an updated fork of TrueCrypt) and then boot into Windows in such a fashion that I can access files from D: at login?

Comment: What would make you think it isn't possible Veracrypt fully supports FDE on MBR partitions.

Comment: I am sure that I can encrypt my boot drive (the SSD) but I am concerned that I will have to encrypt both drives separately, forcing me to login to a Windows user account that doesn't have access to its files (e.g. Desktop directory) at login because the D: drive hasn't been decrypted yet.

Comment: If your program files were not on another disk then this would be possible

Comment: Ah, I suppose that does complicate things. I don't suppose it makes any difference that I keep all my startup programs on my C: drive (at least the startup items I keep enabled)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed possible. Check out the documentation of Favorite Volumes and System Favorite Volumes.

It sounds like you want System Favorite Volumes that will decrypt the D: drive upon bootup. Please note, this requires both drives to have the same password. Here are the links to the detailed documentation.

https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/System%20Favorite%20Volumes.html

https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Favorite%20Volumes.html

Here is how you make a volume a system favorite:

1. Mount the volume (to the drive letter to which you want it to be mounted every time).
2. Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main VeraCrypt window and select ‘Add to System Favorites’.
3. The System Favorites Organizer window should appear now. In this window, enable the option ‘Mount system favorite volumes when Windows starts’ and click OK.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be very useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: I would except those are huge documents that go over several different methods of encrypting the drives, of which I don't know the OP's situation and setup he's looking for so I provided the documents that go over the different methods so he can choose which suits him best. I'll add some more documentation to my post, but not sure how much it will help OP. Thank you for the tip though, I'll be mindful of it.

Comment: Thank you, nikobradshaw. System Favorite Volumes were the answer to my problem.

Comment: @jajavoli awesome! I'll add the instructions for those to my post for others with the same question. Thanks.