# Encrypting Files on Windows 10

Tags: encryption, windows, user-management

I'd like to encrypt a folder on Windows 10. (Full disc encryption doesn't seem possible as the computer has been set up to dual-boot Windows 10 and Linux Mint.)
I need two users to be able to access the folder (one is an admin, the other is not).
What is the best way of making sure both users have access (read and edit) but the folder is encrypted and secure?

Answer (score 0):

Windows full disk encryption is possible also with dual boot. See veracrypt software. 
It install the its bootloader to ask and decrypt the windows disk (partition). 
Remained free space can also used and encrypted by Linux, but grub must be installed on linux partition. To boot into linux you must used the bios f-key to choise the uefi label "linux mint".
I have done it.

Comment: related https://superuser.com/questions/1071660/can-i-use-veracrypt-to-encrypt-both-drives-in-my-laptop

Comment: @jangar, your idea sounds good. Please could you provide slightly more detailed instructions? Does it matter that both Windows and Linux are already installed? I set up the dual boot quite a while ago.